# Correct wiring of 4-wire cooktop to 3-wire 240V supply

Tags: wiring, 240v

I have a new cooktop with 4 wires (see pic) - black, red, white and bare.  The 240V supply cable has black, white and bare.  I measured ~250V across the supply black & white (no load).

The instructions for the cooktop aren’t clear to me ( - shown below). They seem to indicate connecting white and bare (neural & ground), which doesn’t seem right.

My assumption is that in orange supply that black is live/hot, white is neutral and bare is ground.
Update: now wondering if perhaps white is the other hot leg and there is no neutral (would explain why I measure 240V between black & white supply cable)

What should I connect to what?

Thanks!

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is running a ground wire back to the main panel an option?

Comment: I’m not sure - not easily, it runs under the tile floor in a channel.  Isn’t the bare copper wire coming out of the orange supply cable the ground?

Comment: I wouldn't be so quick to make presumptions here....note that this ground wire I'm asking you to run can take whatever path back to the main panel is convenient

Comment: Unfortunately it is an island, so no other ways.  Though there is also a seperate 110V line powering some llights and a power outlet.

Comment: What is below the floor the island is on?

Comment: @Harper -- yeah, technically, you are right, but I think we want to make this install as safe as possible given the constraints imposed by what exists, no?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel ... well... er... yeah, realistically we do.  You're right.  Where you're going is certainly less bad than bootlegging ground.  The underlying cause, though, is some left hand did not know what some right hand was doing, and that right hand had two choices, and chose the cheaper one, saving (are you sitting down?) $4.  Sure hope they enjoyed that frappucino.  Ideal would be go back to the appliance store and get a 240V-only range.

Comment: @DavidJ is exchanging your cooktop for a 240V-only unit an option here?

Comment: Rather not exchange for 240V only, if avoidable.  I have a neutral available from another 110V cable powering drawer lighting - could I just use that neutral?  Maybe the neutral is used by the cooktop only for a 110V supply to power some internal electronics? (i.e. not high amp cooking elements?).  It apparently has WiFi capability and an iPhone app (no idea why what is needed).

Comment: @DavidJ is there nothing but a slab under the island/kitchen floor, or is there a joist space underneath instead?

Comment: @DavidJ no, stealing neutral from a nearby circuit is absolutely forbidden.  The neutral would then be overloaded with the normal return current from that circuit plus the return current from this one, and that would be a serious problem because *neutrals don't have breakers!* Also, that would violate the "wire in tree topology, no cross connections" axiom of wiring, and would cause eddy current and GFCI problems as neutral current would not match the hot current in the other circuit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Building on a ton of comments)

Your cooktop needs two hots + neutral + ground.

Your supply cable has two hots + ground. That is a problem.

The cooktop instructions allow for two hots + neutral, using the neutral for neutral + ground together. This is supposed to be only for old installations (i.e., grandfathered), which is (a) not recommended for safety reasons and (b) likely not allowed in your case anyway. **Not an option.**

There is, often, an allowed fix (again, supposed for old installations only, but it is *safe*). That is to retrofit a ground from elsewhere. But that only works if you have two hots + neutral and are missing ground. But you have two hots + ground, and that means the third wire is not insulated (and if it were insulated, it would be green, which is a ground-only color). **Not an option.**

Unlike ground, you can't pull a neutral from another circuit. That would run the risk of overloading that neutral - and neutrals are not protected by breakers like hots are. **Not an option.**

I only see 2 options:

- Switch for a 240 V only cooktop.
- Run a new cable that includes two hots, neutral and ground. Maybe you can run a cable the ugly way - up to the ceiling (i.e., through cabinets) and along the ceiling around to wherever the breakers are? Or use the old cable (depending on how it was installed) to pull a new cable in to replace it.

Comment: I am just boggling my mind at how the inspector *even passed that*.  Failing to provision a neutral wire to a 30A stove circuit is just *inviting* a ground bootleg later on, a scheme outlawed for new work as of 1989.  The inspector should have insisted that the builder show that he had a very specific no-neutral range in mind.

Comment: My guess is originally cooktop elsewhere in kitchen. Kitchen expanded. Island added for new cooktop and workspace. Electrician didn't think ahead **or** was a general handyman /builder and didn't know what to get, and no inspections. When I redid /expanded my kitchen 18 years ago I got a really professional and knowledgeable and conscientious electrician and looking back (I didn't understand much of this at the time) he really did things right (except he should have sold me on a bigger subpanel). But not everyone is so lucky.

Answer (score 1):

The cooktop wants a 240 circuit and a 120. The two hots are the 240 (120 each and out of phase to add up to 240). The return wire (not safety ground) is used with just one of these phases to make a regular 120 circuit. You'll need X-3 wg wire, where X is whatever gauge is needed for your installation.

Comment: The safest "X" is 6... I.e. 6/3. That will support almost any range/oven on the market.